Next.js handle refresh-token rotation on the client side
So I'm working on a small task-managing web-app with an auth-system. This is done through refresh-token rotation and access tokens (both jwt). I've implemented route-restriction in the middleware, but now I have one problem. How can I know on the client side, that the access token is expired and I have to aquire a new one through the refresh token. Is there a way to get the response code of a page before displaying it, so I can tell that the backend-api returned that the token is invalid and I have to get a new access-token before running the request again?
I'm using next-version 14.2.13
I've tried something with getServerSideProps, but that doesn't work as it tells me getServerSideProps" is not supported in app/ (since I use the app router)
I'm fairly knew to next.js and feel like running into a dead end.
Thanks in advance!
